# Task Visibility in Report

Tags: reporting, sharing, activities

We have a report that is showing tasks on accounts.

For the most part is shows only those tasks which a sales person should see as expected according to sharing rules...

However one of my users can see some tasks owned by other people on other peoples accounts: (some is key - not all)
S1, S2 and ISR.

ISR has task on S1's account. The report shows this to S2
S2 has no child object items (opportunities, tasks, contracts, contacts etc) on this account.

Sharing settings for Activites are Private. For accounts and contacts they are private but with rules to share sideways from Sales hierarchy to Sales Enablement hierarchy (but not the other way)

When I sign in as the user and click into the items that are shown in the report (Contact, Account, Task) the links for Acc and Cont are prohibited for the user but the task is visible.

If I'm missing something - I will answer questions... I cannot see the issue.

Comment: What's the report hierarchy been saved as?

Comment: @Girbot - I have edited the post: it really is only a few... I see 2,279 records but  user sees 293

Comment: Are all of these users in the same role?

With private activity sharing record access as well as the role hierarchy determine who can see the activity.
 See:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sharing_model_fields.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.12

Comment: @gorav They are in the same role, there is no activity sharing and S2 doesn't see all of the tasks for S1 or ISR, or even all of the ISR/S1 combination..

Comment: If they are in the same role, that doesn't mean they will see the same tasks.  They would not see each other's tasks, for example.  They should all see the tasks assigned to accounts that they have read access to.   Can isr see s1s account?  What type of report are you running?  And is the task directly related to the account or does it roll up from related contact or opportunity?

Comment: ISR can see all accounts. S1 can see only his accounts. S2 can only see his accounts. S1 can see all of ISR's tasks on his accounts (can see ALL tasks on his accounts) BUT can also see some of ISR's tasks on S2's accounts (not all - it is to be noted). S1 cannot view the account or any of the contacts. Just the task